# Find table name on the database using stored procedure on MySql 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This is a list name of tables stored a database `MySql version 8.0.17`

```
+------------------+
| listTable        |
+------------------+
| Table_A2_11_2021 |
| Table_L7_12_2021 |
| Table_C3_1_2021  |
| Table_D8_10_2021 |
| Table_T0_11_2021 |
| Table_E9_3_2021  |
| Table_L4_2_2021  |
| Table_O1_12_2021 |
| Table_P2_5_2021  |
| Table_Q2_10_2021 |
| Table_A3_12_2021 |
| Table_S5_9_2021  |
| Table_T8_11_2021 |
| Table_Q6_1_2021  |
+------------------+
```

The `table name` storage policy is

- Table_
- Western alphabet letter (issued by an algorithm that recognizes the connected user, privileges, etc.)_
- Random number_
- Month Number_
- Current Year

I need find on the database MySql all the table for first `Western alphabet letter` without `Random_number` for this return

```
+-----------------+
| listTable       |
+-----------------+
| Table_A_11_2021 |
| Table_L_12_2021 |
| Table_C_1_2021  |
| Table_D_10_2021 |
| Table_T_11_2021 |
| Table_E_3_2021  |
| Table_L_2_2021  |
| Table_O_12_2021 |
| Table_P_5_2021  |
| Table_Q_10_2021 |
| Table_A_12_2021 |
| Table_S_9_2021  |
| Table_T_11_2021 |
| Table_Q_1_2021  |
+-----------------+
```

I have idea to use this Stored Procedure below but I just can't extract first `Western alphabet letter` without `Random number`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_SIX_MONTHS`()
BEGIN

DECLARE tyear INT(4);
DECLARE tmonth INT(2);

SET tyear = YEAR(CURDATE());
SET tmonth = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH));

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT 
                 FROM information_schema.TABLES 
                 WHERE table_name LIKE ''table#_',???,'%#_',tmonth,'#_',tyear,''' ESCAPE ''#'';');                       
                                 
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

**UPDATE**

return of suggestion

```
+------------+
| t          |
+------------+
| Table_A_13 |
| Table_C_12 |
| Table_D_1  |
| Table_E_5  |
| Table_L_12 |
| Table_O_8  |
| Table_P_12 |
| Table_Q_6  |
| Table_S_14 |
| Table_T_4  |
+------------+
10 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Comment: I suggest you use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead of LIKE. Then you can use more sophisticated regular expressions, not just the simple pattern-matching of LIKE.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for suggestion. But if I use REGEXP instead of LIKE how I find month and year in the table name?

Comment: What does "first" mean?  SQL tables represent unordered (multi)sets.

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis you want to remove the random number after western alphabet letter or you want to select all the tables which doesn't have random number in that position.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I need remove the random number after western alphabet letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think this actually does what you want:

```
select min(listtable)
from t
group by substr(listtable, 7, 1);
```

This interprets "first" as "first alphabetically".

If you don't want the digit, you can remove that:

```
select min(insert(listtable, 8, 1, ''))
from t
group by substr(listtable, 7, 1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae42e11e4043fa50f58d2a1291fcf943) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks, pls see the return of your suggestion on  **UPDATE** in the question

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  That is the the result set that I see.